# vectors and the area of parallelogram

Tags: vectors

On vectors $a = 14i -2j +5k$ and $b = -2i+6j-11k$ is parallelogram. Calculate its area. My idea is  to find cross product $a \times b =  (-8 , -144, 80)$ and the compute lenght of this vector , it is $\sqrt{8^2 + (-144)^2 + 80^2} = 40* \sqrt{17}$ . IS it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The area of a parallelogram can computed as $$A=|\vec{a}\times \vec{b}|$$ the so-called cross product.
I got $$\vec{a}\times \vec{b}=<-8,144,80>$$

Comment: So here , $ \vec a$ x $\vec b $ i get (-8,-144,80) , right?

Comment: I think it is $$+144$$?

Comment: Isn't it determinant $$
    \begin{matrix}
    14 & 5  \\
    -2 &  -11 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$
?

Comment: i will check it again

Comment: Sorry, i got the same result $$[-8,144,80]$$

Comment: oh,i understood. but anyway the lenght of this vector is  $40* \sqrt{17}$  ?

Comment: Yes, this is the right result!